# Number of selected individuals for eaSimple algorithm from DEAP with selBest selection

Tags: python-3.x, deap

I am trying to run the `eaSimple` algorithm from the [DEAP module](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html). I would like to specify the number of individuals to be selected at each generation. However, if I specify a `k` parameter for the [selection function](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/tools.html#deap.tools.selBest), I get an error.

```
from deap import base, tools, creator, algorithms
import random
import numpy as np

def fitness(individual):
    x = individual[0]
    y = individual[1]
    return np.exp(-9*x*y) * np.sin(3*np.pi*x)**2 * np.sin(3*np.pi*y)**2,

toolbox = base.Toolbox()

creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, random.random, n=2)

toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

toolbox.register('evaluate', fitness)
toolbox.register('mutate', tools.mutPolynomialBounded, eta=.6, low=[0,0], up=[1,1], indpb=0.1)
toolbox.register('mate', tools.cxUniform, indpb=0.5)
toolbox.register('select', tools.selBest, k=50)

pop = toolbox.population(n=100)

pop, logbook = algorithms.eaSimple(pop, toolbox, cxpb=0.5, mutpb=0.1, ngen=100)
```

The last line in this example raises the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-5ee0faee2c49> in <module>
----> 1 pop, logbook = algorithms.eaSimple(pop, toolbox, cxpb=0.5, mutpb=0.1, ngen=100)

/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/deap/algorithms.py in eaSimple(population, toolbox, cxpb, mutpb, ngen, stats, halloffame, verbose)
    163     for gen in range(1, ngen + 1):
    164         # Select the next generation individuals
--> 165         offspring = toolbox.select(population, len(population))
    166 
    167         # Vary the pool of individuals

TypeError: selBest() got multiple values for argument 'k'
```

Note that replacing the line `toolbox.register('select', tools.selBest, k=50)` with `toolbox.register('select', tools.selBest)` removes the error.

---

What is the default value of `k` here, and how do I specify my own value for `k` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `eaSimple` algorithm, no selection is actually done. From [the documentation](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/algo.html#deap.algorithms.eaSimple), the pseudo-code describing what goes on under the hood states

```
population = select(population, len(population))
```

This means that a subset of the population the size of the initial population i.e. the entire population is selected to be mutated, mated and evaluated.

Then the algorithm does

```
population = offspring
```

so all of the individuals that result from the mutating and mating replace all of the parents.

---

This also (kind of) answers the second part of the question: it isn't possible with `eaSimple` to specify a custom value for `k` in the `selBest` method.